# Node.js - why do I get leaks when testing with mocha and zombie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

I've tried to make zombie work with mocha, but unless I use the mocha --ignore-leaks command options, my test always fails with the error:

```
Error: global leaks detected: k, i, name, chars, char
```

My test looks exactly like the one explained in this thread:
[Mocha and ZombieJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350232/mocha-and-zombiejs)

I wish I could have posted my question there, but as a newbie, I cannot comment on the thread, only ask a new question.

Do you have any idea why I get these leaks? I'm using mocha 1.0.3 and zombie 1.0.0.

Answer (score 6):

The leaks can come either from your own code or from node_modules that you use. Mocha should give some hints on where the leaks are, such as forgetting to declare local variable with **var**.

```
// global leaks
a = 1;

// no leaks
var a = 1;
```

You might also be interested writing Node.js app in coffeescript since it helps you avoid mistakes like that. (**It automatically initializes variables, using var**) http://coffeescript.org/

There is a template that helps you get started here https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee