# nodejs 'util' is global sometimes?

Tags: node.js

I have a model with a function call of `util.endsWith(str, end)` but I forgot to import my util file. Normally I would expect an error like:

`cannot call method 'endsWith' of undefined` or something like that

but the error I am getting is:

`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'endsWith'`

which indicates that `util` is defined. I did a console.log of it and found that it is the same object you get from `require('util')`.

I certainly did not require the util module in this, and I can't find anywhere in my files where I do so (not that I would expect something require-ed in another file to be in this file).

Interestingly, `util` is only defined if I require this module from somewhere else; if I just run the file then `util` is undefined.

Is this normal?

---

My files are not that complicated (<100 lines each) but I have not been able to replicate it with a super basic example. Maybe it has to be a couple of levels deep.

nodejs 0.10.12

Comment: a lot can go wrong with ~100 lines of coffeescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you forgot doing `var util` somewhere in a different module where `util` is being assigned to. This results in a global variable being created.

You may be leaking more global variables this way.
You can get an overview which globals are being created by doing:

```
var oldGlobalNames = Object.keys(global)
```

at top of main script. Then do

```
console.log(_.difference(Object.keys(global), oldGlobalNames))
```

on bottom.

This uses the `difference` function from [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

Or use https://github.com/aheckmann/gleak module.

Another idea: do a project-wide search (including node_modules dir) for `util =`. Get a sense of where `util` is being assigned to.

See also [Node.js - why do I get leaks when testing with mocha and zombie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545449/node-js-why-do-i-get-leaks-when-testing-with-mocha-and-zombie)

Comment: as I understand it, that is not how node modules work. In any case this javascript was generated by coffeescript, so it is impossible to 'forget' to put `var`

Comment: I think what you are saying is correct for the browser, but I am not in a browser.

Comment: Pagoda is correct. All node modules are executed inside a wrapper function so variables declared with `var` are within the scope of the module's wrapper function and thus not visible to other modules.

Comment: How about first establishing that the problem is indeed a global variable `util`? Is `global['util']` set at end of script? Or even more precise, is it set right after the line that produces `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'endsWith'`? (if you fail to include your own util module, that is).

Comment: @PagodaJosh, if it's only 100 lines of code, just paste the code!

Comment: If it's indeed a global that's the culprit, a third-party module could be at fault as well. It's virtually impossible to accidentally leak global variables if you use CoffeeScript throughout, I think. But still, maybe you have some regular JS code as well.

Comment: @MerynStol I owe you an apology; it **was** a third party js module that was leaking stuff. I was under the impression that global variables could not be created in nodejs, so I did not investigate that at first.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad this one mystery is solved! Do file an issue (or do a pull request) with the owner of the misbehaving module. That potentially saves a headache for some future developers. :) In projects with lots of dependencies, I think the origin of such a leak could be hard to track down.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a repl vs script interpreter thing. When you run the repl (either `node` or `coffee`), indeed `util` is available as a pre-imported module it seems. However, when you run them and pass a script argument, `util` is not there:

```
node -e 'console.log(util)'

[eval]:1
console.log(util)
            ^
ReferenceError: util is not defined
    at [eval]:1:13
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at evalScript (node.js:532:25)
    at startup (node.js:80:7)
    at node.js:901:3
```

However, with the repl:

```
node
> util
{ format: [Function],
  deprecate: [Function],
  print: [Function],
  puts: [Function],......
```

Comment: yes, I had noticed that all the regular modules are global in the node REPL, but I am launching my code with `node myfile.js` so I don't think that it is.

Comment: @PagodaJosh I thought you said you were using coffeescript? So why not `coffee myfile.coffee` ?