# run all 'test.html' files in a directory - mocha-phantomjs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, phantomjs, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

I have a module, I am testing this module using mocha-phantomjs. I created `package.json` file

```
{
  "name"        : "demo-test",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test-debug",
    "test-debug": "mocha-phantomjs ./test/Test1.html"
  },
  "dependencies" : {
    "mocha"     : "1.13.x",
    "commander" : "1.2.x",
    "which"     : "~1.0.5",
    "mocha-phantomjs": "3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies" : {
    "chai"          : "1.8.x",
    "coffee-script" : "1.6.x",
    "requirejs"     : "2.1.x",
    "jquery"        : "2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Then I run `npm install` and then `npm test` to run the test. It works fine and run the tests of `test1.html`. 
Now I want that all the files (test1, test2, ...) under test directory get executed on running `npm test`.

I can run all html files by calling then individually in package.json file but if there is a way to load all Html files.

Comment: This [link][1] can help you. Also check [this][2] link.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281561/using-mocha-phantomjs-to-automate-functional-testing
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376269/how-to-run-mocha-and-mocha-phantomjs-tests-from-one-npm-test-command-in-node-j

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would pass a **Tests.html** file to your **mocha-phantomjs** runner that would load up all of the test files that you want to run using script tags.

**Tests.html** would contain:

```
<script src="controller-tests/one-controller-test.js"></script>
<script src="controller-tests/another-controller-test.js"></script>
<script src="controller-tests/yet-another-controller-test.js"></script>
<script src="service-tests/one-service-test.js"></script>
<script src="service-tests/another-service-test.js"></script>
<script src="service-tests/yet-another-service-test.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, if you are using **[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)** or another [AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) library, you could load one **test-init.js** file and, within that file, require-in all of the test files individually or in a nested manner as follows:

**Tests.html**

```
<script src="test-init.js"></script>
```

**test-init.js**

```
require('controller-tests/init.js');
require('service-tests/init.js');
```

**controller-tests/init.js**

```
require('one-controller-test.js');
require('another-controller-test.js');
require('yet-another-controller-test.js');
```

**service-tests/init.js**

```
require('one-service-test.js');
require('another-service-test.js');
require('yet-another-service-test.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with DanAri.

I use the same bootloader and testing setup.

**Mocha BDD**

Presumably, by default, running Mocha in "BDD" mode looks for html files in a "test" directory in the root of a project. It starts by looking for a file named "test.html". "test/test.html" is the default path target for Mocha to use as a fixture file.

**Regarding RequireJS/AMD**

Regarding client-side (AMD) flavor RequireJS, I use a binary branching pattern.

```
-index.html
  |
  -/js/rjsMain.js
-test/test.html
  |
  -/js/rjsTest.js
```

I separated my RequireJS configuration section into a new file (I call mine "rjsConfig.js"). This file contains the path aliases, dependency shims, et cetera.

So, then my RequireJS "data-main" file "/js/rjsMain.js" looks like this:

```
require(['rjsConfig'], function () {
    require(['app/main'], function () {});
});
```

I then duplicated the Require "main.js" file to add an alternate entry point for my Mocha fixture file .

The reason for this is so that you don't have to maintain two separate configuration files for Require. It's nice to have one shared file.

**PhantomJS**

Getting PhantomJS to actually load and interact with content that is loaded asynchronously? That is another matter. It can be quite tricky.

Fortunately, I found a file that does the trick.

It doesn't have a very good name, but - for me at least - "load_ajax.js" is the secret sauce you need to get it to work.

https://gist.github.com/kalharbi/fc9d4f71b5e2a8f485cc

You need to customize it to run against your local routes.