# Advanced front end test framework for node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I am working on a node.js + express application.

And what I am trying to do is defining a strong test base to work with.

So I read this really [nice article](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-tests_for_user_signup) which explains how to develop a simple application with ruby on rails.

And I read the following lines of code which inspired me a lot :

```
visit signup_path
fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
click_button "Create my account"
```

So here I come to the point. Is there a way to write a similar piece of code using node.js and its dependencies ?

I am currently using mocha 1.x, should 1.2.x and supertest 0.6.x but they didn't seems to fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like zombie.js or selenium (js-webdriver) which test your code from the browsers pov. I recommend taking a look at zombie.js first.

Comment: And it seems to be well integrated with mocha (another related question here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9444550/657524).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/). Nettut's has a great tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/testing-your-javascript-with-jasmine/

Answer (score 0):

[Mocha.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) is a popular choice as well, especially if you're into Coffeescript

Comment: `I am currently using mocha 1.x`