# Node.js TypeError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

I am trying to use zombie.js to log into a site but I keep on getting this error.

`TypeError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`

I think that it has something to do with the websites security but I'm not for sure. Here is the code that I am using.

```
const Browser = require('zombie');
Browser.localhost('test.com', 3000);
describe('User visits signup page', function() {
const browser = new Browser();
before(function(done) {
    browser.visit('/', done);
});
describe('submits form', function() {
    before(function(done) {
        browser
        .fill('Username', '*******')
        .fill('password', '*******')
        .pressButton('Submit', done);
    });
    it('should be successful', function() {
        browser.assert.success();
    });
    it('should see welcome page', function() {
        browser.assert.text('title', 'Welcome To Brains Depot');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9444550/2295034

Answer (score 1):

This problem threw me for a bit of a loop, because my tests would run fine on one machine, but not on the other. By providence, the working machine had my application running with `nodemon` in the background. I didn't realize `zombie` doesn't start a test server for you. The non-working machine didn't have a server running, so the tests failed. To fix your problem, you could include something like this in your test file or setup:

```
const app = require('../../app');
const http = require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

If the server's running the tests should also run without crashing.